# selecting parent of selected child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

First off, forgive me if this is a redundant question. I think you'll agree that it's a difficult case to reasonably specifically search for.

I have html that looks like

```
<li class='signature'>
    <span class='label'>Signature:</span>
    <div class='folding'>
        <span class='data'></span>
    </div>
</li>
<li class='issuer'>
    <span class='label'>Issuer:</span>
    <span class='data'></span>
</li>
```

etc etc.

I want to use jquery to do an .addClass only to any li that contains a div of the class "folding", but not to the other lis. I'm sure that I can do this using a cunningly-crafted .each statement, but I kind of feel intuitively that there must be a way to do this using just jquery selectors. I have gotten as far as

```
$('li > .moreclick').addClass("arrowable");
```

but that of course adds the class to the span, and not to the li.

Am I stuck with an .each? (and if so, any hints on the best way to do that would be nice, but admittedly outside the scope of the question).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `li` is always going to be the absolute parent:

```
$("div.folding").parent().addClass("new-class")
```

Otherwise, this will keep searching up the hierarchy until it finds an `li`:

```
$("div.folding").closest("li").addClass("new-class")
```

[edit]
dioslaska's solution is much nicer. Keeping mine here for reference though.

Comment: Your solution is a better one. Dioslaska's solution will break here: http://jsfiddle.net/Svqdc/ while yours will work as expected.

Comment: Yes, itt will break, but this was not the specified case. E.g. if you place somewhere another div with "folding" class which has an li ancestor, this solution will brake as well adding an unwanted class to the li. (No offense to the solution though, it's totally correct and I really don't know which selector is faster)

Comment: Aha, I see the difference between the two. Very useful for comparison, thank you both @Luke and @dioslaska. I'm checking this as the solution, I'll have to wait until the html is frozen to know which one I'm going to use, but I'm annoyed that I haven't yet gained enough karma to upvote both solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
$('li:has(.folding)').addClass("arrowable");
```

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Comment: What's the practical difference between what you've done here and "$('li').has" suggested by @littlealien below? Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
$('.folding').parent().addClass('arrowable');
```

//edit too slow..

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$('li').has('.folding').addClass("arrowable");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check only the direct children of li:

```
$('li:has(> div.folding)').addClass("arrowable");
```

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know you could do this with >, that's good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$("li:has(div.folding)").addClass("new-class")
```

This will selects exactly the `li` element which is the parent of `divs` that have class `'folding'`.

Comment: In comparing this to dioslaska's solution above, I did not realize you could specify div.folding in this way. That's good to know, thanks!